# SQL Data entities Entity Association

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have about 8 entities that all have a one to one relationship with a common entity.

The client is not choosing from pre-defined data so it is not necessary to apply a FK to be used as a constraint.

The main table in question is call a finish table and it contains four unknown hex colors that are sent from the client to the server.

For example, when a door is built the colors for the different parts of the door and it's outer parts can all have different colors. So, all of these tables in question, their data is always fresh from the client and not chosen from a drop down, or from some other pre-defined data that I am given to the client to choose from.

My question is, what would be the best way to association this finish entity with the other entities that need a way to express their finish?

I am adding a screen shot of a diagram that I am working on, these are not all the entities and are just the ones in question right now and ones that will help articulate to others what I am needing a solution for.

I have also included some script as well.

```
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Finish]    Script Date: 06/22/2012 15:08:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Finish](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Left] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Right] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Top] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Bottom] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Finish] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Horizontal]    Script Date: 06/22/2012 15:08:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Horizontal](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(11,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Floor] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SizeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GlassPocket] [decimal](5, 3) NULL,
    [IsFiller] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Horizontal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Door]    Script Date: 06/22/2012 15:08:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Door](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(421,1) NOT NULL,
    [BayID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [HasJamb] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasThreshold] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAutoShowroom] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSingle] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SizeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Door] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Leaf]    Script Date: 06/22/2012 15:08:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Leaf](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(21,1) NOT NULL,
    [DoorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Stile] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Bottomrail] [decimal](5, 3) NOT NULL,
    [Hand] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Swing] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [SizeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Leaf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Bay]    Script Date: 06/22/2012 15:08:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bay](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1213,1) NOT NULL,
    [ElevationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SizeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bay] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Each one of the entities below need to be associated with the finish table. Each entity new record has exactly one finish relationship.
Is it possible to associate these and still be able to do a Cascade On DELETE, with-out having a circular reference issues?

[image: Schema Candidate]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your requirements for cascading deletion?  Which record do you anticipate being deleted, and which (related) records do you anticipate needing to be automatically deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You would add a reference to Finish entity in each of the tables that has a relationship to it.

You would define the column with the same datatype, (and normally) as the referenced_table_name and id. In our shop, the column_name would be [finish_id]. (I see here that you are using a CamelCase style.)

At any rate, I would recommend you define this as a foreign key.

You say there is no need to, but from what you describe, this is exactly the kind of situation that calls for a foreign key constraint.

You need to decide on the action when the id in the finish table is updated or deleted. (Do you want to disallow the update or delete? Do you want to preserve existing relationship?) I expect you would want the default ON DELETE RESTRICT.  You could allow for updates, and preserve the relationships, with ON UPDATE CASCADE.)

I don't see any potential problem with circular references, as long as the finish table will be the parent (all the other tables reference it, and the finish table doesn't have any references to the other tables.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the , "That's what we're doing info". I always ask a lot of questions when I begin to design a database, they're just to hard to undo.. ;) As far as the on delete, the way I am approaching this is it is not possible to delete a finish for a child. So, what you're saying, is to place a FK into a entity as the door table from the finish table. When door is deleted grab finishID and delete the finish record.. Thank you for the help.